# Permutation of a number of rows of a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, permutation

I have a data frame of this kind:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'Job': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'Machine1': [1,3,2,4,3], 'Machine2': [2,0,5,1,2]})
```

For the index `'Job'`, I need to find all permutations of length 5, basically (5 factorial) permutations. The length of the index may change for a different scenario, so I am not looking for a code specific to 5 jobs only.

Expected output: `A,B,C,D,E; A,C,D,E,B; E,D,C,B,A ...` and so on up to 120 such ways. In basic math, it is a permutation expressed as 5P5

Comment: Please clarify and provide a sample of your expected output.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to permute the entire dataframe rows? only the list/Series in the 'Jon' column `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`? So this is just a question about permutations in Python, not permuting rows in pandas? Your title seems to disagree with the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the built-in function [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools as it
permutations = list(it.permutations(d['Job']))
```

Output:

```
>>> permutations
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'E'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'C'),
 ('A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D'),
...

>>> len(permutations)
120
```